# Spring Tool Suit Generate JPA Entity from Database : Solution

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

G9 plugin from Marketplace in Spring Tool Suit or Eclipse did job done.

1. Install Plugin G9
2. Select Project (JAVA)
3. Import "Import Database Model"
4. Select JDBC Driver (In my case mysql)
5. Maintain JDBC Connection

   - New
   - Provide *Driver Name, Add Jar, Port, Driver Class and connection url along with schema (jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/{schema_name})*
6. Close JDBC Connection Box
7. Port, DB Name, User Name and PWD
8. Fetch

Reference URL https://www.esito.no/produkter/dbimport/